# Hibernate 6.1.x - extract epoch function is not working any more

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-17

```
   @Query(value = "select " +
            "cast(extract(epoch from tx.dateCreated) as long)   " +
            "from TransactionHistory tx " +
            "where tx.id = :id ")
    List<Long> findTimeStats(@Param("id") final String id);
```

When I try the above code in spring boot 3.0.6, hibernate 6.1.7.Final and Java 17, it throws the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:26 no viable alternative at input 'selectcast(extract(epochfrom'
```

complete stack trace:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [select cast(extract(epoch from tx.dateCreated) as long) from TransactionHistory tx where tx.id = :id ]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:760)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:126)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy156.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94)
... 168 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [select cast(extract(epoch from tx.dateCreated) as long) from TransactionHistory tx where tx.id = :id ]
at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.parseHql(StandardHqlTranslator.java:130)
at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:77)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:747)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
... 176 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:26 no viable alternative at input 'selectcast(extract(epochfrom'
at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator$1.syntaxError(StandardHqlTranslator.java:46)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:543)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportNoViableAlternative(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:310)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportError(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:136)
at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser.queryExpression(HqlParser.java:1182)
at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser.selectStatement(HqlParser.java:384)
at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser.statement(HqlParser.java:315)
at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.parseHql(StandardHqlTranslator.java:116)
... 181 more
```

The same code is working in spring boot 2.7.x, hibernate 5.x and Java 11. After the migration this extract part is no longer working.

When I change the extract part in the query to year, it is working fine:

```
cast(extract(year from tx.dateCreated) as long)
```

It seems the epoch extract is not working.

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace

Comment: is `tx.id` really a string?

Comment: Why do you do *cast(extract(epoch from tx.dateCreated) as long)* in SQL not in the code?

Comment: Yes tx.id is a string

Answer (score 0):

Changing the JPQL query to Native query resolves the issue now.